# Sorting and cleaning huge list of django admin modules

Tags: django, django-admin

I'v got a django app with a lot of model classes. The app in itself is split into python modules, but in my django admin, all those models belongs to a single django app, and they [show up in the same block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkuoD.png), making it hard to find the module you are looking for.

Is there a way to split this huge block of links, without moving the models to different apps?

Thanks.

Comment: Errr, did you ever consider using a document oriented database? okay, you can downvote this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to solve this is to override/extend index.html and/or app_index.html admin template (and maybe others). This way you could put the list as you want. See [Overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) for more details on how to do that.

Comment: It seems there's not easier / cleanier way to do this. This one is a good start, though.